# Form not submitting values to coldfusion

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

I have an HTML form that submits to a Coldfusion action page. For some reason, the form struct does not come through? The 2 files `index.cfm` and `add.cfm` are both in the same directory. When I submit the form the test text in the processing page shows, but not the form. I also do not see the form variables in the CF debugger.

What am I missing?

**index.cfm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Video Slideshow Admin</title>
  <!--- <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> --->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.yt-container {
  padding: 2% 5%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.input-short {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.input-shorter {
  max-width: 100px;
}
.input-med {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.input-long {
  max-width: 800px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="yt-container">
    <h1>Video Slideshow Admin</h1>

    <!-- form -->
    <h2 class="form-title">Add Video</h2>

    <p class="required">* Required</p>

    <form name="vidform" action="add.cfm" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="heading">Heading</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-med" id="heading" placeholder="Heading" value="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="url">Embed URL*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-long" id="url" placeholder="Embed URL" value="" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <select class="form-control input-short" id="status">
          <option ng-selected="formData.type == null">Select</option>
          <option value="show">Show</option>
          <option value="hide">Hide</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="order_seq">Order Sequence</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-shorter" id="order_seq" placeholder="Order" value="">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**add.cfm**

```
We are here
<cfdump var="#form#">
<cfabort>
```

Comment: Hard to say because you have all that irrelevant styling code cluttering up the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every form input needs a `name` attribute as well.

This is what Coldfusion is looking for when you post the form.

So:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-med" id="heading" placeholder="Heading" value="">
```

Becomes:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-med" id="heading" name="heading" placeholder="Heading" value="">
```

This goes the same for `<select>` and checkbox / radio

Comment: @mhatch - See also the specs for other rules about which controls can be submitted. [17.13.2- Successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)